# FreeDOS doesn't find partition

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, installation, freedos

I have a computer with Windows 10 and I would like to install FreeDOS on a separate partition and make a dual-boot. I did a flash drive with the FreeDOS USB image because my computer doesn't have a floppy disk driver or CD driver and I allocated an F:/ partition with on FAT16 (C:/ is Windows).

So I used the FDISK command and the Set Active Partition option to see which partition it was recognizing. I found that only the flash drive's FAT partition appears (D:/) and I can't switch to another partition. How can I make the FreeDOS installer recognize the F:/ partition?

Answer (score 0):

For
[FreeDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDOS)
to see your disk, the disk controller must be set to
Compatibility (IDE) mode, not RAID or AHCI.

FreeDOS supports FAT32, so FAT16 is not a must.

Note: It would be much safer to install such an ancient
operating system inside a virtual machine, rather than setting
it to dual-boot with a modern operating system.

Comment: It might be important to point out that by changing it to IDE you will likely not be able to boot into Windows especially if RAID mode is enabled.  There is also the possibility the disk is GPT which is not compatible with FreeDOS.